# Where do I define px to em mapping?

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I heard from w3schools that `1 em = 16px`.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

However, in my Jekyll site

http://madhur.github.com

The standard font in paragraph is 12px even though I have set `font-size: 100%` in `body` and `font-size: 1em`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Imagine if the W3C sold bogus "certificates" for $95.00 like [w3$chools does](http://www.w3schools.com/cert/default.asp)... It's disgusting, I hope not many people have fallen for that trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At line 27 of [`global.css`](http://madhur.github.com/files/css/global.css) the font-size of body has been overridden to 76%, 16px*0.76 = 12.16px

Answer (score 1):

One em is the width of the letter "M" in your standard font and size. em is completely dependent on what you set your font-size and font as. font-size: 1 em pretty much means font-size: 100%;

Em is only 16px if your font-size already is 16px.